# systrace output html only has cpu row

Tags: android, linux, systrace, ftrace

following picture is my systrace output, there is only one row. Comparing the html with some sample file, it seems in my file, there is no lines like

```
  SurfaceFlinger-220   [001] 227112.684875: 0: B|129|onMessageReceived\n\
  SurfaceFlinger-220   [001] 227112.684906: 0: B|129|handleMessageInvalidate\n\
  SurfaceFlinger-220   [001] 227112.684906: 0: B|129|latchBuffer\n\
  SurfaceFlinger-220   [001] 227112.684906: 0: E\n\
```

Is that the reason? How to solve it? I'm using mips android 4.4.2.

[image]

Comment: what do you want then? Showing the logs like sample file?

Comment: Yes, like this one.  http://developer.android.com/images/systrace/report.png. How to do?

Comment: What tags are you specifying?  I don't know how many people have used systrace on MIPS devices, so it's possible something is broken.

Comment: @fadden python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm

Comment: If you look in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-release/cmds/atrace/atrace.cpp you can see how the tags get set.  I'm wondering if somehow the magical Binder SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION message isn't getting through, so the tags aren't being enabled in the target process.  You could try manually setting `debug.atrace.tags.enableflags` to (say) 65535 and restarting the framework and see if more stuff shows up.

Comment: how to manually setting debug.atrace.tags.enableflags,if SYSPROPS_TRANSACTION message isn't getting through? I modified the atrace souce, call setTagsProperty(65535). not wok, get the same result.